# Elastic search cross fields, edge ngram analyzer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I have 999 documents which I am using for experimenting with elastic search.

There is a field f4 in my type mapping which is analyzed and has following settings for analyzer :

```
  "myNGramAnalyzer" => [
       "type" => "custom",
        "char_filter" => ["html_strip"],
        "tokenizer" => "standard",
        "filter" => ["lowercase","standard","asciifolding","stop","snowball","ngram_filter"]
  ]
```

My filter is as below :

```
  "filter" => [
        "ngram_filter" => [
            "type" => "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram" => "2",
            "max_gram" => "20"
        ]
  ]
```

I have value for field f4 as "Proj1", "Proj2", "Proj3"...... so on.

Now when I try to do search using cross fields for "proj1" string, I was expecting document with "Proj1" to be returned at the top of the response with max score. But it doesn't. Rest all the data is almost same in content.

**Also I don't understand why it matches all 999 document?**

Following is my search :

```
{
    "index": "myindex",
    "type": "mytype",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "proj1",
                "type": "cross_fields",
                "operator": "and",
                "fields": "f*"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "deleted": "0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My search response is :

```
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 999,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "42",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "f1": "396","f2": "125650","f3": "BH.1511AI.001",
                "f4": "Proj42",
                "f5": "BH.1511AI.001","f6": "","f7": "","f8": "","f9": "","f10": "","f11": "","f12": "","f13": "","f14": "","f15": "","f16": "09/05/16 | 01:02PM | User","deleted": "0"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "47",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "f1": "396","f2": "137946","f3": "BH.152096.001",
                "f4": "Proj47",
                "f5": "BH.1511AI.001","f6": "","f7": "","f8": "","f9": "","f10": "","f11": "","f12": "","f13": "","f14": "","f15": "","f16": "09/05/16 | 01:02PM | User","deleted": "0"
            }
        }, 
        //.......
        //.......
        //MANY RECORDS IN BETWEEN HERE
        //.......
        //.......
        {
            "_index": myindex,
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "f1": "396","f2": "142095","f3": "BH.705215.001",
                "f4": "Proj1",
                "f5": "BH.1511AI.001","f6": "","f7": "","f8": "","f9": "","f10": "","f11": "","f12": "","f13": "","f14": "","f15": "","f16": "09/05/16 | 01:02PM | User","deleted": "0"
            }
        //.......
        //.......
        //MANY RECORDS IN BETWEEN HERE
        //.......
        //.......
        }]
    }
}
```

Any thing that I am doing wrong or missing? (Apologies for lengthy question, but I thought to give all possible information discarding unnecessary other code).

**EDITED :**

Term vector response

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "mytype",
    "_id": "10",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "took": 9,
    "term_vectors": {
        "f4": {
            "field_statistics": {
                "sum_doc_freq": 5886,
                "doc_count": 999,
                "sum_ttf": 5886
            },
            "terms": {
                "pr": {
                    "doc_freq": 999,
                    "ttf": 999,
                    "term_freq": 1,
                    "tokens": [{
                        "position": 0,
                        "start_offset": 0,
                        "end_offset": 6
                    }]
                },
                "pro": {
                    "doc_freq": 999,
                    "ttf": 999,
                    "term_freq": 1,
                    "tokens": [{
                        "position": 0,
                        "start_offset": 0,
                        "end_offset": 6
                    }]
                },
                "proj": {
                    "doc_freq": 999,
                    "ttf": 999,
                    "term_freq": 1,
                    "tokens": [{
                        "position": 0,
                        "start_offset": 0,
                        "end_offset": 6
                    }]
                },
                "proj1": {
                    "doc_freq": 111,
                    "ttf": 111,
                    "term_freq": 1,
                    "tokens": [{
                        "position": 0,
                        "start_offset": 0,
                        "end_offset": 6
                    }]
                },
                "proj10": {
                    "doc_freq": 11,
                    "ttf": 11,
                    "term_freq": 1,
                    "tokens": [{
                        "position": 0,
                        "start_offset": 0,
                        "end_offset": 6
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED 2**

Mappings for field f4

```
"f4" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "index_analyzer" : "myNGramAnalyzer",
    "search_analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

I have updated to use standard analyzer for query time, which has improved the results but still not what I expected.

Instead of 999 (all documents) now it return 111 documents like "Proj1", "Proj11", "Proj111"......"Proj1", "Proj181"......... etc.

Still "Proj1" is in between the results and not at the top.

Comment: Can you check term vector for one of documents: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Comment: @alpert Updated question with term vector response

Comment: Can you just change your `type` of **multi_match** search query from `cross_fields` to `best_fields` and check again if the results are the desired ones.

Comment: I already tried that and no improvement.

Comment: Can you please send your `myIndex` mappings?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Hope it will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of spending time to find a solution to this, I finally made it work.

So I kept everything same as mentioned in my question, using n gram analzyer while indexing data. The only thing I had to change was, to use the `all` field in my search query as a bool query with my existing `multi-match` query.

Now my result for search text `Proj1` would return me results in an order such as `Proj1`, `Proj121`, `Proj11`, etc.

Although this does not return the exact order like `Proj1`, `Proj11`, `Proj121`, etc, but still it closely resembles the result that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `index_analyzer` (at least not from `Elasticsearch` version 1.7). For [mapping parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-params.html) you can use `analyzer` and `search_analyzer`.
Try the following steps in order to make it work.

Create myindex with analyzer settings:

```
PUT /myindex
{
   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "myNGramAnalyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "char_filter": "html_strip",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "standard",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "stop",
                  "snowball",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Add mappings to mytype (to make it short I just mapped the relevant fields):

```
PUT /myindex/_mapping/mytype
{
   "properties": {
      "f1": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "f4": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "myNGramAnalyzer",
         "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "deleted": {
         "type": "string"
      }
   }
}
```

Index some data:

```
PUT myindex/mytype/1
{
    "f1":"396",
    "f4":"Proj12" ,
    "deleted": "0"
}

PUT myindex/mytype/2
{
    "f1":"42",
    "f4":"Proj22" ,
    "deleted": "1"
}
```

Now try your query:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "proj1",
         "type": "cross_fields",
         "operator": "and",
         "fields": "f*"
      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "term": {
         "deleted": "0"
      }
   }
}
```

It should return document `#1`. It worked for me with `Sense`. I am using `Elasticsearch 2.X` versions.

Hope I have managed to help :)

Comment: Have you tried this by adding document with field f4 as `Proj1`, `Proj11`,`Proj12`,`Proj13`,`Proj121`,`Proj111`, because my stuff is not working for this. It's already working for what documents you have used in you example.

Comment: Also, I am aware about `index_analyzer`  and I am using older version which supports it.

Comment: When I index: 
`PUT myindex/mytype/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "f1":"396","f4":"Proj1","deleted":"0" }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "2" } }
{ "f1":"396","f4":"Proj11","deleted":"0" }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "3" } }
{ "f1":"396","f4":"Proj13","deleted":"1" }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "4" } }
{ "f1":"396","f4":"Proj121","deleted":"1" }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "5" } }
{ "f1":"396","f4":"Proj111","deleted":"1" }`

The documents I get are: `#1` and `#2` isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Also, I saw that the query in the question matches all documents. Did you mean all documents that starts with prog1? Since the result hits contains `proj47`. Can you share what version of Elasticsearch you use?

Comment: It may be getting returned for you and not for me because I my documents are not indexed in the same order, also I am using 1.5.2 For that "Proj42" that is now not getting returned as I have now different index and search analyzers, earlier I was not using it and hence it was getting returned in the response.

Comment: Can you explain why the order of indexing makes a change?
What problem are you facing now that you have changed the index and search analyzers?

Comment: The same issue, I can't get document with "proj1" at the top of result, if you give me some time, probably I will update the question with what I have achieved so far after writing this question.

Comment: Sure, would love to help figuring out the problem :)

Comment: I finally found a solution, please have a look at my answer, and thanks for your help.